# Why is my event throwing a null error?

Tags: c#, events, nullreferenceexception

For some reason my event is throwing a null error.  I don't see anything wrong.

here is the event

```
public delegate void connectionSuccess(bool success);
public event connectionSuccess Connection;
```

then in a function i have this witch throws the null error

```
Connection(true);
```

Edit* function in another class that calls the connection function

```
Server.Connection += onConnection;
Server.startConnection();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is not connected, it is `null`.

Try this instead:

```
var h = Connection;
if ( h!=null )
{
     h(true);
}
```

I'm assigning to a (local) variable first in order to overcome multi-threading scenarios where there are modifications between checking for `null` and calling.

I.e. the following would *not* be thread-safe:

```
if ( Connection!=null )
{
    Connection(true);  // Here, could already be null, again.
}
```

Comment: ill try that in a bit, but it also throws it event if it is true

Answer (score 0):

You need to check and make sure something is actually subscribed to the event before you invoke it.

```
if(Connection != null)
    Connection(true);
```

Comment: im sorry i forgot to mention that before the function is called somthing is subscribed to the event.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have no subscribers yet. When an event has no subscribers it becomes `null`. You have two options to solve this (I prefer the second).

Option 1:

```
if (Connection != null)
    Connection(true);
```

Option 2:

```
public event connectionSuccess Connection = delegate { };
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because a null reference exception will be thrown if there is the **null delegate reference**! So, it is necessary to check the delegate reference.

It is a good practice to create an **event invocator** - helper method. It simplifies calling the event handlers.

For example, let's take a look at `Book` class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface:

```
class Book : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name == value)
                return;

            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Event invocator.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Property name.</param>
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

More detailed information about the implementation of event invocators is here: [Events and Races](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should check the initialization of your objects.  While your code does make it look like everything is in the same class, I'm not sure why you would go through the headache of creating events instead of just calling the method.

HOWEVER, if your raising the event in one class and attempting to handle it in another, you may run into the same thing that I did.  Let me explain...

MDIParent - Contains the instantiation code for the child form.  Also has the code to wire the event handler of the child to the code on the MDIParent.

```
Form x = new MyTestForm();
x.OnMyEvent += this.HandleEvent(myEventArgs);
```

MDIChild - Contains the code that we use to create the event and actually trigger it.

```
public MyTestForm()
{
    public event EventHappened MyEventHandler;
}
```

Later in the code, we actually raise the event.

```
MyEventHandler(new MyEventArgs(this, "some message");
```

The problem that I was having with all of my event handlers, which we were using to update a StatusBar, was that the wiring up of the event wasn't happening until the form was completely initialized.  This means that all of the work in setting up the form was complete by the time we actually wired the event TO something!

How did I get around this, you ask?  Well, I moved all of the initialization code into a separate method and out of the constructor.  We call the constructor to create an instance of the form, wire the events up, and THEN run through all of the form's creation tasks.

Hope that this helps someone!  I spent days trying to figure out why my events were null when I could plainly see that they were assigned!